# Criteria and Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have an entity: Order Detail. It look like as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
public Product getProduct() {
    return this.product;
}
public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

@Column(name="amount",nullable = false)
public int getAmount() {
    return this.amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount= amount;
}

@Transient
public void setSum_amount(double sum_amount){
    this.sum_amount=sum_amount;
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of order details, group by products, and the amount of each product in Order Detail table.

This is my code to do that:

```
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<OrderDetail> od=session.createCriteria(OrderDetail.class) 
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
            .add( Projections.sum("amount"),"sum_amount")
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("product"))
    )
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(OrderDetail.class))
    .list();
```

The issue is that I can not access to the product property, doing "od.getProduct().getName()" i get the nullpointerexception, so, how could i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not really getting a list of order details but list of sums for each order detail group. So, you are getting numeric values from SQL. Therefore, I think, you are getting list of empty `OrderDetail` (because of transformer) objects with only `sum_amount` set on them.

Your problem can't be solved in its current form as your query is not getting order details but completely different objects. You should rethink what you are trying to achieve and how.

Comment: I just want to get the products which have more quantity in Order Detail table, the best selling products.

Comment: Then your criteria should be built on top of `Product.class` not `OrderDetail.class`. And result would be a product. Have you constructed SQL query that gives you desired result? Start with it and then it will be much easier to figure Hibernate query.

Comment: I'm not sure of the correctness of these sentences: `Select od.idproduct Sum(od.amount) from OrderDetail od group by od.idproduct order by Sum(od.amount)` or `Select od.idproduct sum(od.amount) from OrderDetail od group by od.idproduct order by sum(od.amount)=(Select Top 10 Sum(od.amount) from OrderDetail od group by od.idproduct order by 1 desc)` But anyway, i don't know how to do it using Criteria.

Comment: Are you trying to get products with most orders or with most money spent on them? Do you only need top 10 of them?

Comment: I need the products with most orders, this is the relationship among the tables: Products 1 ->n Order details n<- Orders. That's right, I only need 10.

Comment: Try this query against db and see if it works and does what you need. `select * from (select * from PRODUCT p join (select o.productId productId, count(o.orderId) orderCount from ORDER_DETAILS o group by o.productId) counts on counts.productId = p.productId order by counts.orderCount desc) where rownum<=10;`

Comment: I got an error: Every derived table must have its own alias. And insted of count(o.orderId), it should be sum(o.AmountofProducts), one order can have a number greater than 1 of the same product.

Comment: What db do you use? You will have to debug this query to do what you need. I can't try it since I don't have your DB and schema.

Comment: You probably need an alias before last `where`. I gave you Oracle way, btw

Comment: you were right, that alias was missing. I'm using Mysql, the following sentence works fine: `select * from (select * from 'db'.'PRODUCT' p join (select o.productId productId, sum(o.AmountOfProduct) orderCount from 'db'.'ORDER_DETAILS' o group by o.productId) counts on counts.productId = p.productId order by counts.orderCount desc) queryAlias;` I had to omit `rownum<=10;`, it seems like mysql doesn't recognize it, but I could do it using Criteria:`crit.setMaxResults(10)`. The problem I face now is translating that sql sentence to Criteria query.

Comment: you don't need to use last `select` without rownum. `rownum` should work but it's irrelevant as in Hibernate you just call `setMaxResults()`

Comment: You should consider accepting answers that people gave to your questions. Or you will not be getting much help in future.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Projections` to group things, you are limiting by definition what comes back from your query.  In your example above, you are only returning 2 columns, so the @ManyToOne association isn't being initialized.  Once you have the result set, try looping it, and for each record, use `Hibernate.initialize` to load up the association.